# How to change google map lat and lon on load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have google map that is being pragmatically added to a page scaffold that I need to interoperate and change depending on certain lat, lon and zoom variables.

The map is already being created and is showing the default lat, lon and zoom, I need to sneak in and change these either before or as the map is being created.

Below is my unsuccessful attempt at changing the parameters. Lat, lon and zoom variables are being set properly. the gmap selector is where the current map is being displayed.

```
        var latitude = lat;
        var longitude = lon;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: zoom,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new GMap(document.getElementById("gmap"), mapOptions);
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        map.setCenter(latlng);
```

Is the "map = new Gmap" not working because it is an existing map?

Comment: How are you creating the original map? Currently you are creating a new one, not changing the existing one. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip it is being added by the gmap drupal module, which is above my head at the moment. I'll keep trying to figure it out though

Answer (score 0):

```
var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
```

source: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: unfortunately it does not update the existing map, it is still loading the default coordinates

Comment: you need to fetch the existing map variable and center that.